# QFile: File content gets deleted when program crashes

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I'm having a little problem with QFile.
I write a small log file during a process, but due to the performance (at least I think so) I don't close the file after each write, but only at the end. Instead, I use .flush() , but when the programme crashes, the file is completely empty.

Does anyone know what the reason could be? I would not like to open and close the file before and after each write process, as I am running processes every millisecond and do not want to impair performance too much.

```
Classname::Classname() {
    m_LoggingPath = "cameraLogging_"+QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd_MM_yy hh_mm_ss")+".txt";
    m_LoggingFile.setFileName(m_LoggingPath);
    m_LoggingFile.open(QIODevice::Append);
    m_LoggingStream.setDevice(&m_LoggingFile);
}

Classname::~Classname() {
    m_LoggingFile.close();
}

 void Classname::logAction(QString action, QString data){
    m_LoggingStream << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss.zzz")
        << " Action: " << action
        << " Data: "   << data
        << " \n ";
    m_LoggingStream.flush();
    m_LoggingFile.flush();
}
```

Comment: No idea. Try using `std::endl` instead of `\n` as that flushes automatically (that's the reason it's considered evil!).

Comment: @Vorac there is no need for `std::endl`, OP explicitly calls `m_LoggingStream.flush();`

Comment: The code looks correct to me. Are you sure the `Classname::logAction()` function is called before the crash?

Comment: @vahancho Yes I am sure that logAction() is executed several times before the programme crashes. I also find it strange.
If I simply close the programme using TaskManager, the file is correctly preserved, but when the programme crashes internally, the file is empty.

Comment: As a workaround, use `std::fopen` in append mode, and `std::fwrite` to write raw data, and `std::fflush` to flush.

Answer (score 1):

Normally OS doesn't write files instantly. Instead all writes are buffered for certain amount. Especially if the media is something like SSD or Flash. For the latter small writes result in rewriting whole file allocation block or two adjacent, which usually ranges between 512 and 4096 bytes. Small writes reduce life of flash  disks by pinpoint writes.

For similar reasons on some OSes and file systems metadata of file, i.e. it's size and, may be not updated until file is closed.

It's a good idea either to use OS-provided API or facilities for logging or use a mature logging library instead of dancing on same old garden rakes every time.

Comment: +1 Some call to [sync](https://manpages.org/sync/8) is being missed and preventing that is IMHO in no way a developer's job. Your last paragraph is. One level of abstraction up. Happier life.

Comment: @Vorac afaik Qt intentionally doesn't use sync. That thing is questionable on mobile devices if they write on FAT-formatted memory card